# Given the value of centroids of each cluster, how can other points be assigned a numeric value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cluster-analysis

I know some associated value of the centroid of the cluster and I want to assign values to the other points in the cluster which are unknown. How can I do this?

[image: clusters image]

In the picture above, say I want to assign values to `P1` and `P2` and the `X` is centroid which I know the value of.

A bad approach I think would be to just use the `distance from the centroid of the cluster` to the points as some sort of `weight and multiply it with the centroid value`, but that would mean `P1` and `P2` if they are `equidistant get the same value`. I think this doesn't work well because if X and Y axis are representing some features then P1 is clearly more in magnitude in both these features and P2 is just the `opposite`. What could be a better way for doing this?

Comment: There are different ways to calculate the distances and different algorithms will work different with distance, here you can see different algorithms and distances used on them: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html. Here the example of Agglomerative Clustering: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering --> options: Metric used to compute the linkage. Can be “euclidean”, “l1”, “l2”, “manhattan”, “cosine”, or “precomputed”. If linkage is “ward”, only “euclidean” is accepted.¶

Comment: You could create different features as well, here examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099958/density-clustering-around-a-separate-point-python/66189973#66189973

Answer (score 0):

The point of `clustering` is to assign every point in the `cluster` the value of the `centroid`.

Comment: Yes, but points in the same cluster can be far or away from the centroid so in my opinion they should have a slightly different value. One way I think is to create clusters where the maximum distance between the centroid and the point is limited by a threshold, then I can assign every point the value of the centroid since they are close enough. The thing is I also want to minimize the number of clusters for my application. The centroids would have to be manually assigned a value and hence I want to reduce them.